# Left indent names of skills in awesome-cv LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, awesome-cv

[image: How do I align the skills to left side?]
How do I align the skills to left side?

```
\cvsection{Technical Skills}
  \begin{cvskills}
    \cvskill
      {Programming Languages:}
      {Java, Python, C, C++, R, JavaScript}
     \cvskill
       {Web Technologies:}  
        {HTML5, CSS3, XML, AngularJS, PHP, JSON, Ajax, .Net}
     \cvskill
        {Databases:}  
        {Oracle 12c, SQL, MySQL, MongoDB}
      \cvskill
         {Platforms/Tools:}  
         {Amazon EC2, Docker, Linux, Eclipse, Visual Studio, GIT}
     \end{cvskills}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable code you have so far. Please change personal informations to dummys, thanks.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer, if it was the most helpful one for you. That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 3):

You need to redefine environment  `cvskill`  like this:

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\renewenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
  }
```

Please see that I changed the original `r` in the `tabular` definition to `l`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
%\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{%
  showframe,
  left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm
} % Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parallel}


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

% Colors for text - uncomment and modify
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

% Define an environment for cvskill
\renewenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
  }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~--~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Education}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something else} % Degree
{University} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Another one} % Degree
{College} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}


%------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Technical Skills}
  \begin{cvskills}
    \cvskill
      {Programming Languages:}
      {Java, Python, C, C++, R, JavaScript}
     \cvskill
       {Web Technologies:}  
        {HTML5, CSS3, XML, AngularJS, PHP, JSON, Ajax, .Net}
     \cvskill
        {Databases:}  
        {Oracle 12c, SQL, MySQL, MongoDB}
      \cvskill
         {Platforms/Tools:}  
         {Amazon EC2, Docker, Linux, Eclipse, Visual Studio, GIT}
     \end{cvskills}

\cvsection{Skills}
{ % start group for font
% \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont
  \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\bodyfontlight\color{text}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 2 text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 3 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
} % end group

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just a hack:

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}

\newcommand\addSpace[1]{#1\hfill}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

How do I align the skills to left side? How do I align the skills to left side?

\cvsection{Technical Skills}
  \begin{cvskills}
    \cvskill
      {Programming Languages:}
      {Java, Python, C, C++, R, JavaScript}
     \cvskill
       {\addSpace{Web Technologies}:}  
        {HTML5, CSS3, XML, AngularJS, PHP, JSON, Ajax, .Net}
     \cvskill
        {\addSpace{Databases}:}  
        {Oracle 12c, SQL, MySQL, MongoDB}
      \cvskill
         {\addSpace{Platforms/Tools}:}  
         {Amazon EC2, Docker, Linux, Eclipse, Visual Studio, GIT}
     \end{cvskills}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]